# Angular anchorScrolling Issue

Tags: angular

I enabled [anchorScrolling](https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#anchorScrolling) on my RouterModule. My scenario is taking the user directly to a field when routing to a new page. This works fine for the most part. However, the issue I am having is for fields that are contained inside `*ngIf` logic. These fields do not exist right away so the anchor scroll logic doesn't see the field and never scrolls to it.

Is there a workaround for this scenario?

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
  scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
  anchorScrolling: 'enabled'
})

<input class="form-control" name="fieldAnchorTagHere" />
```

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: @MCMatan I added some code to my question. There isn't much logic. Thanks.

Comment: @RyanBuening exactly your logic is missing. You show the code which is working. Where is `*ngIf`? What does it actually check for?

Comment: @MCMatan - Sorry, I wasn't very clear. My view model is populated from a back-end service call. Based on those values, fields show/hide. So I need to delay the anchor scrolling until that completes. I think I have a solution and posted an answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add this to my `ngOnInit` after my view model was populated. Once the view model is populated, the necessary fields show and the querySelector / scrollIntoView works.

```
        activatedRoute.fragment.subscribe((fragment: string) => {
        if (fragment) {
            const element = document.querySelector('[name=' + fragment + ']');

            if (element) {
                element.scrollIntoView();
            }
        }
    });
```